# How to make a in game gamble script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a gambling script in my unity game where players can "Invest" their in-game currency to try and x5. However, I'm getting a few errors.

I'm confused on the errors, It seems pretty simple to make, just errors pop up :/

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Investment : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static double BakeryInvestmentCost = 1000;
    public static double BakeryInvestmentReward = 5000;
    public double genChance;
    public static double Jackpot = 6;

    public void BakeryInvestment()
    {
        GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins - BakeryInvestmentCost;
        genChance = Random.Range(1, 6);
        if (genChance = Jackpot)
        {
            GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins + BakeryInvestmentReward;
            Debug.Log("You Won!");
        }else
        {
            Debug.Log("You Lost :(");
        }

    }
}
```

> (25,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
>
> (27,13): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'bool'
>
> (29,13): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Explain what you think statements like `GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins - BakeryInvestmentCost` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `a -= b` or `a += b` means `a = a - b` or `a = a + b`

```
GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins -= BakeryInvestmentCost;
GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins += BakeryInvestmentReward;
```

I believe you are having a typo, assume `GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins` is a double. Increment/reduction on wining/losing the gamble.

```
if (genChance == Jackpot)
```

A single `=` means you are assigning the `Jackpot` into `genChance` which is not allow as the error message stated: `(27,13): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'bool'`

`a == b` means you are comparing b to a

You might want to take extra note on your syntax in C#

Comment: thank you so much it worked, yeah I forgot the = sign.

Comment: However, I lose every time, there is now a win? Why is that?

Comment: @VastShadowZ Try to use `Random.Next(a, b)` as it will return you a random number from `a` to `b`. Since `.Next()` return a random number of `int`, it is recommended that you have your `genChance` declare as `int`

Comment: Ive added "public System.Random ran = new System.Random();" and "genChance = ran.Next(1, 2);" and still a loss every time :/

Comment: @VastShadowZ i see, Random.Range() is a method in unity refer [Unity - Random](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html). Then you don't have to change anything, it will always have a random number from 1 to 6. It not you lost everytime, maybe you just dont have the luck i guess.

Comment: That's what I thought until I pressed it over 50 times :/ im so confused. I changed the Range from (1, 6) to (1, 2) and still the same thing.

Comment: @VastShadowZ did you have your `Jackpot` assigned as 1 or 2? and declare `genChance` as `int`

Comment: I have the ```Jackpot``` set to 1 right now. And everything was changed over to ints

Comment: Okay, I guess changing everything to Ints worked, No Clue why it didn't work last time. Thank you!

Comment: Your jackpot variable is 6. Random.Range with integers has an exclusive upper bound. So Random.Range(1,6) gives numbers 1 to 5 as possible results.